# Qual é a diferença entre o relacionamento com "identificação" e relacionamento "não-identificação"?(Mysql Workbench)

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql, relacionamento

Estou aprendendo Banco de Dados há algum tempo e não sei a diferença. Eu gostaria muito saber. Na internet até achei respostas, mas elas não são muitos esclarecedoras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relacionamentos com e sem identificação são conceitos de MER (Modelo Entidade Relacionamento). Na prática, um relacionamento **com identificação** é aquele que é representado por uma chave estrangeira que é parte da composição da chave primária da tabela referenciada. Um relacionamento **sem identificação**

Dando um exemplo do mundo real:

Um livro pertence a uma pessoa, e a pessoa pode ter vários livros. Mas o livro também pode existir sem a pessoa e ele pode mudar de proprietário. A relação entre um livro e um proprietário é uma relação **sem identificação**.

Um livro, porém, é escrito por um autor, e o autor pode ter escrito vários livros. Mas o livro precisa ser escrito por um autor, ele não pode existir sem um. Então, a relação entre o livro e o autor é uma relação **com identificação**.

Exemplo da relação **com identificação**:

```
CREATE TABLE LivroAutores (
  autor_id INT NOT NULL,
  livro_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (autor_id, livro_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (autor_id) REFERENCES Autores(autor_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (livro_id) REFERENCES Livros(livro_id)
);
```